# Can anyone describe how this assembly code is working?

Tags: assembly

```
CODE SEGMENT
ASSUMECS:CODE, DS:CODE, ES:CODE, SS:CODE
PPIC_C EQU 1FH
PPIC EQU 1DH
PPIB EQU 1BH
PPIA EQU 19H
ORG 1000H
MOV AX, 0
MOV AL, 10000000B
OUT PPIC_C, AL
MOV CX, 50
MOV AL, 11101110B 
L1: OUT PPIB, AL
PUSH CX
MOV CX, 0 
LOOP $ 
POP CX
ROL AL, 1
LOOP L1
HLT
CODE ENDS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is probably working with a Programmable Peripheral Interface 8255.

It starts by writing 0x80 to the PPI control register, which configures Port B as an output port.

It then writes a bit pattern in `AL` 50 times to Port B, with a software delay between each. After each write to Port B, the data in `AL` is rotated left. The bit that falls out of the top bit 7, is rotated into the bottom bit 0. So the value repeats every 8th write.

What it actually does, will depend on what is connected to the PPI port B.

Answer (score 0):

Port 1Bh is written 50 times in a row each time with a slightly different value.
Between writes some time is spend to allow for the peripheral to react.

```
PUSH CX
MOV CX, 0 
LOOP $ 
POP CX
```

This is a delay loop.